# feeding distance matrix to R clustering from Rpy2

Tags: python, r, numpy, cluster-analysis, rpy2

I have the following custom made NxN distance matrix in numpy/scipy:

```
dist_matrix =    array([array([5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3]),
                        array([4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2]), 
                        array([2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1]), 
                        array([3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2]), 
                        array([2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1]), 
                        array([3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5])])
```

how can I use this matrix to do hierarchical clustering and plot dendrograms in R / ggplot2? If I try to feed this distance matrix into R via rpy2 as:

```
r.hclust(dist_matrix)
```

I get the error:

```
   res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Is `dist_matrix` an NxN array, or is it a 1d array of 1d arrays with shape `(N,)` and dtype `object` as it seems to be shown?

Comment: @askewchan: I can make it in either format... I tried both and get the error... but anyway I can transform back and forth between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R function `hclust()` is taking "distance" objects:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr("stats")
d = stats.as_dist(m)
hc = r.hclust(d)
```

[note: the error message is also hinting at a possible conversion bug in rpy2. Can you file a bug report ? Thanks]

Comment: Any idea on how to do this with version 3.x? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398908/how-to-use-hclust-function-from-r-in-python-via-rpy2-v3